# Sometimes the highlighted version of my button does not show when pressing the button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have defined several states for my button programmatically

And sometimes they work, sometimes not.

I extended the UIButton and wrote this inside its initWithFrame and initWithCoder methods

this is my definition:

```
[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage buttonBackgroundImageNamed:@"bigbutton_normal"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigbutton_pressed"]
                forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigbutton_pressed"]
                forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigbutton_disabled"]
                forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

However, sometimes i press the button, and only bigbutton_normal is shown, the action of the button is carried out as needed.

What can I do to fix this issue ?

Comment: Why did you subclass `UIButton` when those methods are public?

Comment: because I wanted it to look a certain way and do some extra stuff, without needing to constantly set it up in every viewcontroller it is added to

Comment: Can you show the complete method please.  Also there are alternatives to subclassing; for example create a method which performs the button-setup and call that from each view controller.